# Convert Excel sheet data in array

Tags: javascript, html

I get data from google Sheets in the following format which I want to convert to another format.

```
[ 
  [ 'Teresa', 'lname', 44, 'hindi', 'math', 'sci' ],
  [ 'Conn', 'de', 55, 'hindi', 'math', 'che' ],
  [ 'Caterina', 'ddd', 33, 'math', 'hindi', 'bio' ],
  [ 'Papagena', 'dd', 42, 'math', 'hindi', 'geo' ],
  [ 'Fabien', 'des', 33, 'hindi', 'eng', '' ] 
]


[ 
  {name:'Teresa', lastName:'lname', age: 44, subjects:['hindi', 'math', 'sci' ]},
  {name:'Conn', lastName:'de', age:55, subjects:['hindi', 'math', 'che' ]},
  {name:'Caterina', lastName:'ddd', age:33, subjects:['math', 'hindi', 'bio' ]},
  {name:'Papagena', lastName:'dd', age:42, subjects:['math', 'hindi', 'geo' ]},
  {name:'Fabien', lastName:'des', age:33, subjects:['hindi', 'eng', '' ]}
]
```

I am trying to learn but am not able to do it. Please help...

Comment: Add your attempt to solve your problem in your question.

Comment: Dear just on stackoverflow there might be like 100 question on this subject. Do a quick search, Im sure you will be able to find something to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

```js
const data = [
  ["Teresa", "lname", 44, "hindi", "math", "sci"],
  ["Conn", "de", 55, "hindi", "math", "che"],
  ["Caterina", "ddd", 33, "math", "hindi", "bio"],
  ["Papagena", "dd", 42, "math", "hindi", "geo"],
  ["Fabien", "des", 33, "hindi", "eng", ""]
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const obj = {};
  obj.name = cur[0];
  obj.lastName = cur[1];
  obj.age = cur[2];
  obj.subjects = cur.slice(3);
  
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! 
Now i am able to create that ... Thanks alot,

Comment: Thank you so much !! 
Now I am able to create that ... Thanks a lot, I do not know any languages of programming but out of my curiosity, I am able to learn some basic Tricks... and basics.

["Teresa", "name", 44, "Hindi", "math", " "] ... here I am getting some blanks for blank cells.. not an issue I can delete it manually.. but if there is a fix... Thanks